# Git and Intellij weird interaction with Git (VCS)

Tags: git, intellij-idea, version-control

Everytime that I launch IntelliJ, at the indexing point, the whole project gets blue, which means that I have made changes in the files (which I didn't), at the moment I can't really show the problem with images. 
If I revert my project to a previous version, make no changes but turn off the computer, in the moment that I turn it on, open the IntelliJ and wait for indexing, all files will show as changed.

[Print for better understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCNl4.png)

Comment: Are the files really changed? It might be some line endings change or executable bit change. What does `git status` in the command line show?

Comment: No, they didn't change, but if a try to push it with git, even if I have modified only 1 file, all the 900+ (which is my case) are going to shown as modified in the log. Without the bug: "Your branch is up to date with 'origin/developLucas'." With the bug: "Your branch is up to date with 'origin/developLucas'. Okay, that didn't helped as much, I'll ask for permission and try to add a print.

Comment: @DmitriySmirnov, print added for a better understanding of the problem.

Comment: The screenshot shows files as ADDED - in green, while you mentioned they are listed in blue. The entire project can get ADDED status if for some reason it gets mapped to a different repository, which does not have those files tracked. Likely that was the reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the solution was simple:

Basically what I did was delete the folder and redo all the git configuration (that's the second time I did that), after that, I cloned the repository and checked-out to my branch, as I said, after restart, in the moment that IntelliJ indexes the files it was being marked as changed, and now it doesn't do anymore.

I'm not sure what caused this bug, but now it's working so that's ok.
Hope this question help someone in the future and thanks @Dmitriy Smirnov for the attention.